# How to compare one large dataset in DB and one large dataset on SpreadSheet?

Tags: sql, excel

I am trying to compare two large dataset which have two columns- Company name column and Contact person name column. One dataset is already in database and one set is on Excel SpreadSheet. 
I try to compare two dataset and try to update database.

For now I download data from database and comparing two dataset using Pivot Table function in Excel. This kinds of work. But I hope is there any other better way. Any suggestion will be appreciated!! Thank you.

FYI my database uses MSSQL 2008.

Answer (score 0):

Upload the data from the excel work sheet as a csv file to the database, and save the contents in a different table. Then compare both tables with a join.

Answer (score 0):

Upload your excel file as .CSV to database, next either create a table for it or just use a temporary table to place the data from the CSV file. Proceed to compare the data from that temporary table to the table on your DB with a Join.